# Java.net.URI constructor is not encoding & character

Tags: java, android, kotlin, urlencode

I am trying to create a URL where the query parameters contain a symbol &. When I am passing this to Java.net.uri(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class constructor its not encoding the & symbol to %26.

Example: https://www.anexample.com:443/hello/v5/letscheck/image/down?name=tom&jerry&episode=2

Now tom&jerry is the value of the query parameter but when we pass this to Java.net.uri constructor it encodes all spaces and special symbols but does not encode & to %26.

So tom and jerry both become separate query parameter which I don't want.

code will look something like below:

```
String query = "name=tom&jerry&episode=2"

URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, query, null);
```

I have also tried encoding the query parameters myself and then sending it to the constructor like below:

```
String query = "name=tom%26jerry&episode=2"

URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, query, null);
```

But in this case the encoded parameter becomes tom%2526jerry as % is encoded to %25

So how can I encode it so I can send & inside as a query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like below?

```
String tomJerry = "name=" + URLEncoder.encode("tom&jerry", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String episode = "episode=" + URLEncoder.encode("2", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String query = tomJerry + '&' + episode;
URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, query, null);
```

A better way would be looping through the key value pairing of the queries and applying `URLEncoder` to the value then joining the rest of the query with `&` after or perhaps `stream`, `map` then `collect`. But the point is to encode the value part of the query string.

Comment: This answer is correct. The only thing I had to do different is not pass query again to URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, query, null); because this will encode all the encoded % into %25 again. Instead I created my url using URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, null, null);
and then concatenate query using uri + "?" + query

Comment: The answer is not correct, because the "%"s from URLEncode.encode will be encoded again by the URI-constructor. The solution outlined in the comment is quite different from the answer.